# conemu (windows terminal program): text not visible in emacs

Tags: emacs, conemu

I am running the most recent alpha build 160503 of the ConEmu terminal / console program on Windows 7.  I start a console window running the cygwin bash shell.  I can start "emacs -nw" (terminal-based, no window), and everything works fine.  I then ssh to a remote machine.  emacs -nw then opens emacs, but certain text is not visible.  For instance, if I open a file (C-x C-f) or start a shell in emacs, the text I type is not visible until I hit enter.  This is true even if I change the color scheme.

I am stumped!

Comment: Bugs of ssh.exe must be reported to its maintainers. The problem does not relate to ConEmu. You are running emacs on remote machine, so only ssh is responsible for displaying its output.

Comment: it has nothing to do with ssh, I can confirm that in local conemu cygwin bash emacs showing white symbols in place of letters (I also assume that it has smth to do with elnode mode). Maximus it would be very helpful if you would actually listen to feedback to conemu and not pinpong issues with it instead.

Answer (score 0):

I used to click Ctrl-l to adjust the output of ssh in a remote console.
It is also recommended that you use tramp(of emacs) to ssh to a remote machine. It is more stable and safe when you do remote works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting ssh, then tmux, then emacs. It's working